# Dynamically create a onClick event handler with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code which builds a table from array called 'data'. I would like to add javascript call into my other method called backend_getMovieData, but I dont know how to build a string from movie._id. I'm getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " from my example code.

```
data.forEach(function(movie) {
    $("#shows").find('tbody')
           .append($('<tr>') 
           .append($('<td>' + movie._id + '</td>'))
           .append($('<td>' + movie.total + ' times</td>'))
           .append($('<td><button class=\'btn btn-success\' onClick=backend_getMovieData(' + movie._id + ');>Show times</button></td>'))); 
});
```

Comment: Are'nt you missing the quotes around `backend_getMovieData(' + movie._id + ');`?

Comment: If I change this line: onClick=backend_getMovieData(' + movie._id + ');
into something like: onClick=alert(\'test\');
my code is working

Comment: @Mino What is that `<br/>` for ?

Comment: Oh, they are just some edits on stackoverflow question. I will edit them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your function is expecting a string.

Do this:

```
data.forEach(function(movie) {
    $("#shows").find('tbody')
           .append($('<tr>') <br />
           .append($('<td>' + movie._id + '</td>'))<br />
           .append($('<td>' + movie.total + ' times</td>'))<br />
           .append($('<td><button class=\'btn btn-success\' onClick="backend_getMovieData(\'' + movie._id + '\')";>Show times</button></td>'))); 
});
```

You need to wrap it with quotes.

Comment: OK, now im getting into the actual problem. Now its saying Uncaught ReferenceError: Uroot is not defined. And that Uroot is movie._id variables value.

Comment: @Mino, I think `backend_getMovieData` accepts a string. Try my above code.

Comment: Yes it actually works! Thank you. I have too many quotes in my javascript code so I was just a bit confused :).

Answer (score 1):

JQuery can get it done with a bit more finesse:

```
$("#shows").on('click', 'button.btn-success', function() { backend_getMovieData(this.id) });

data.forEach(function(movie) {
    $("#shows").find('tbody')
       .append($('<tr>') <br />
       .append($('<td>' + movie._id + '</td>'))<br />
       .append($('<td>' + movie.total + ' times</td>'))<br />
       .append($('<td><button class="btn btn-success" id="' + movie._id + '">Show times</button></td>'))); 
});
```